# Php error views template

Tags: views, theming, i18n-l10n

I am trying to implement this function in my code, to handle language fallback, but it doesn't really work: The content is not in the correct language. I am trying to use `field_language('node', $node, 'field_exhibition_event_image')` without success.

My original views template contains the following code.

```
<img src="<?php print image_style_url('550x250', $row->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_exhibition_event_image['en'][0]['uri']);?>" alt="Images"/>
```

I want to change the code to something similar to the following one.

```
<img src="<?php print image_style_url('550x250', $row->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_exhibition_event_image[field_language('node', $node, 'field_exhibition_event_image')][0]['uri']);?>" alt="Images"/>
```

What would the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution for my problem can be found [here](https://drupal.org/node/2020785) if anyone else is interested:

https://drupal.org/node/2020785

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Drupal Answers. May you provide a summary of what reported in the linked page? Link-only answers are not considered answers, on Stack Exchange.

Comment: ah sorry i am a newbie

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you should not directly call `field_language()` to get the value of a field in the language that should be used to render it; for that there is the [field_get_items()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) function, which in fact calls `field_language()`.

```
function field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, $field_name, $langcode = NULL) {
  $langcode = field_language($entity_type, $entity, $field_name, $langcode);
  return isset($entity->{$field_name}[$langcode]) ? $entity->{$field_name}[$langcode] : FALSE;
}
```

`field_language()` is directly called (for example) from [comment_tokens()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.tokens.inc/function/comment_tokens/7), since it needs to pass the language code to [_text_sanitize()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!modules!text!text.module/function/_text_sanitize/7).

```
if ($items = field_get_items('comment', $comment, 'comment_body', $language_code)) {
  $instance = field_info_instance('comment', 'body', 'comment_body');
  $field_langcode = field_language('comment', $comment, 'comment_body', $language_code);
  $replacements[$original] = $sanitize ? _text_sanitize($instance, $field_langcode, $items[0], 'value') : $items[0]['value'];
}
```

Comment: Aha, thank you for the help. But how do i put this into the field_get_items function?

field_language('node', $row->_field_data['nid']['entity'], 'field_exhibition_event_image')

I always get WSOD